# Print Array in Ruby with Multiplication

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm trying to wrap my head around Ruby and was wondering if anyone on here could help me with my problem.

I want an array that goes up to 5.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Then I want it to print that array and also include it in an equation, of sorts.

So, something like this:

```
puts (56 * arr) + (30 * (arr-1)) =>

56
142
228
314
400
```

Essentially, I want to further print something like so:

```
puts ".col-"arr" { " (56 * arr) + (30 * (arr-1)) "px };"
```

So it prints something like this:

```
.col-1 { 56px; }
...
```

Is this possible using Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr.each { |n| puts ".col-#{n} { #{56*n + 30*(n-1)}px; }" }
```

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you so much! If I can just pick your brain for a moment, could you explain how it's doing that or point me to some sort of documentation. What does the "|n|" mean for example, and what are the point of the #?

Comment: the `n` in between the `||` is just a variable. It could be anything, but n is good for numbers. The `each` method iterates through the part between the outer `{ }`. So it takes the first element of the array (represented by `n` and goes through the block of code. Then it takes the second element, and does the same thing, and so on. I would take a look at codecademy.com. They have an excellent basic tutorial on Ruby. Then I would look at rubymonk.com for review/more learning.

Comment: Also, the code in between the `#{}` makes it possible to write ruby within double quotes. That's how we can call the `n` from within the quotes, and it still outputs that element of the array.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I did that Try Ruby course not so long ago, I'll give Rubymonk.com a look too. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 1):

The per-element computation is easy with `Array#map` or `Array#each`.

```
> arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> arr.map{|elem| 56*elem + 30*(elem-1)}
=> [56, 142, 228, 314, 400]
> arr.each{|elem| puts ".col-#{elem} { #{56*elem + 30*(elem-1)} px };" }
=> the CSS
```

Comment: Thanks for this! What does "elem" mean?

Comment: So, what's between the pipes is a block? So this can be anything, right?

Comment: `elem` is merely a variable, like the `n` in the example above. The variable is declared between the `||` and then is used later in the block of code.